# Resultado de um Submit dentro da própria DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma div(id=conteudo) onde carrego outras paginas via jquery load. porem gostaria de saber se é possivel submeter um formulario e ter o retorno na propria div.

```
   $('#conteudo').on('click', '.menu', function () { 
   $('#conteudo').load(this.href); 
   return false; });
```

Atualmente quando é um link comum consigo ler a pagina com o codigo acima , estou tentando usar a seguinte forma.

```
   $('#conteudo').on('submit', '#form', function () { 
   $('#conteudo').load(this.href); 
   return false; });
```

É possivel isso ?

Comment: não manjo muito de JQuery mas pelo que entendi você chama `load` passando por parâmetro o caminho, no caso o atributo `href` do link, para fazer o mesmo no formulário não seria só trocar o `this.href` por `this.action`?

Comment: Vc quer submeter um formulário?

Comment: ja tentei isso nao funciona, sempre abre em uma outra pagina

Comment: @dvd sim quero submeter o formulario e retornar o mesmo na propria div que foi chamado